# what will be the parameterization of cone

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have question, I need more idea. can any one answer my question I have tried but i didnot get full idea I know this question we have to use parameterization of cone which i donot know in this case for that i ask this question again

> **Q**
>   Determine the result of parallel translating the vector $(0, 0, 1)$ once around the circle $x^2+ y^2=a^2, z=0$

in this case 1)what will be the parameterization of cone and

2) what will be the geodesics equation (differential equation for cone in this case)

thanks

Comment: You have asked this same question in 3 or 4 different posts here. The reason you're not getting any answers is because the question doesn't make sense. Maybe you copied it from a textbook or a homework assignment. If, so, you didn't copy it correctly or completely. In this version, you didn't give the equation of the cone. Without that, the question is impossible to answer. In other places, you talk about "the cone $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$". As I have told you, this is **not** a cone.

Comment: For part 2, I guess you meant to ask "what are the differential equations satisfied by geodesics on a cone". Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

For part 2, I will give you hints. You have a parametrization of the cone, and you need to calculate the Christoffel symbols, which will give you the equation for the geodesics $\ddot x^\mu+\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\gamma}\dot x^\nu\dot x^\gamma=0$.

I suppose you need the geodesics considering the cone embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ with the euclidean metric, and so the line element of the underlying space is just $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$, you have a function for the cone in the form of $z=f(x,y)$, so you can get $dz$ from there, substitute in the above to get the induced metric in the surface of the cone, and then calculate the Christoffel symbols. This is the long straighforward way.

I will outline a different way. We though need a "intuitive" known fact, which is that the cone can be transformed to the euclidean plane, and the length of paths don't change, like in the image:

[image]

that means you should get straight lines in the plane for the geodesics. If in the euclidean plane geodesics are just $x^\mu=v_0^\mu\lambda+x_0$, where $\lambda$ is the parameter of the geodesic, then in polar coordinates they're:

$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c}\qquad\qquad \theta=\arctan\frac{y}{x}=\arctan\frac{A\lambda+B}{C\lambda+D}$$

where $A,B,C,D,a,b,c$ are constants that determine the path (there must exist a relation between them which I have not calculated).

Now, can you find the change of variables between the polar coordinates and the coordinates in the cone? Can you verify they actually satisfy the general equation with the calculated Christoffel symbols?

Also be carefull when the $\arctan$ does whole rounds in the cone, the equation for $\theta$ is only valid interval-wise.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1 -- I already gave you a parametrization of a cone in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373364/what-is-the-right-circular-of-cone-and-what-is-the-right-circular-of-cylinder/373381#373381).