# Calculating half-angle of cone of rays entering pinhole camera

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics, computer-vision

I have the following pinhole camera:

[image]

The cone of rays that would enter the pinhole from the object would resemble the following:

[image]

(Image from https://www.optilayer.com/products-and-services/tools/cone-angle )

I want to calculate the half-angle $\alpha$ of the cone of rays that enters the pinhole camera:

[image]

(Image from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373381/356308) (Bubba's) answer.)

I am told that the half-angle is $\alpha = \dfrac{R}{-l}$, where $R$ is the radius of the pinhole. However, I am unsure of what trigonometry/geometry was used to find this. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to carefully explain this to me.

Comment: Notice that the "incident" part of the picture makes two right triangles. The long side of both of these triangles is equal to $-l$ (as noted in the picture). The short side is equal to half of the height of the little arrow. The angle would then fulfill the equation
$$
\tan{\alpha} = \frac{R}{-l}
$$
And for small values of $\alpha$, we can approximate $\tan{\alpha} \approx \alpha$, when $\alpha$ is in radians.

Comment: @MattiP. thanks for the comment. I understand everything you've said, but I'm confused about how $R$ fits into this. $R$ is said to be the radius of the pinhole, but we are conceptualizing it here as not necessarily just the radius of the pinhole, but also the radius of the entire ray? Please clarify/explain.

Comment: @MattiP. In other words, if $R$ is the short side of our triangle, then $R$ would get larger the farther we move away from the pinhole. But if we said that $R$ is the radius of the pinhole, then how does this make sense, because now we are changing what $R$ is?

Comment: So $R$ would not be a constant representing the radius of the pinhole, but rather a function that represents the radius of the cone of rays depending on the position along the cone (as I said, $R$ would get larger the farther we move away from the pinhole). At the origin, $R$ would represent the radius of the pinhole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: pinhole camera]

The expression for the half-angle $\alpha$ makes sense if we draw the incident light cone differently--with a point on the object as apex and the circular pinhole as base. For consider that the object is emitting light in all directions from each point on its surface, but just a cone of the hemisphere of light rays from each point passes through the pinhole. The pinhole is the base of all these cones, but each has for apex a different point on the luminous object.

In the figure, let $GH$ be the object, $CD$ the diameter of the pinhole, and $EF$ the projection screen. If $J$ is a point on the object, $K$ the center of the pinhole, and $JK\perp AB$, then$$JK=-l$$and $$CK=R$$ $\triangle CJD$ is a cross-section of the cone of light emanating from $J$, and half-angle $$\alpha=\angle CJK$$

Thus$$\tan \alpha=\frac{CK}{JK}=\frac{R}{-l}$$Of course this supposes that the cone of light passing through the pinhole is a *right* cone. For a point like $G$ the cone is slightly oblique, and the expression for $\tan \alpha$ is only approximately correct. Thus it holds best if the object is small in relation to its distance from the pinhole. Note too that if $R$ is too great, the image of a point on the object, such as $J$, will be blurred from $J'$ to $J''$ on the camera back. Thus the smaller $\alpha$ is the better, and then, as @Matti P. notes, in radians$$\tan\alpha\approx\alpha$$

There appear to be various conditions and limitations on the workings of a pinhole camera to be taken into account, but this may be enough to resolve the difficulty in question.

Comment: Excellent explanation!!! Thank you very much for taking the time to do this! When the cone is thought of as you suggest, the confusion I had is dispelled, since $R$ is now fixed at the pinhole. As for the aforementioned approximation, here is a note-to-future-self/readers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation