# Radius of the paraxial impulse response of a pinhole camera

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, physics, computer-vision

I have the following pinhole camera:

[image]

The cone of rays that would enter the pinhole from the object would resemble the following:

[image]

(Image from https://www.optilayer.com/products-and-services/tools/cone-angle )

One of the first elements of image quality is point spread function, the distribution of light in the image plane caused by an infinitesimal point of light on the object. This concept is also sometimes referred to as impulse response.

**I want to find the radius of the paraxial impulse response of a pinhole camera with pinhole radius $R$ illuminated by an on-axis object point.**

The first step is to find the half angle $\theta$ of the cone of rays that enters the pinhole from the object. In the comments to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3424291/356308) question, Matti P. explains how $\theta = \dfrac{R}{-l}$.

[image]

(Image from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373381/356308) (Bubba's) answer.)

The provided solution then proceeds as follows:

> The size of this cone at the image plane is $\theta(−l + l′) = R \left(1 − \dfrac{l′}{l} \right) = R(1 – M)$. Since $|M|$ is usually $<< 1$, the impulse response is thus just somewhat larger than $R$.

I am confused as to how one comes to this solution. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Comment: I think this suits physics SE more...

Comment: @Szeto It seems to me that this is more-so a geometry/trigonometry question than a physics question, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing two different things. What your images show is how much of the outside world you see in the camera. The impulse response is something different, like a resolution for the camera. Let's select a point outside, along the axis of the camera. You can see the image in the center of the camera as a tiny circle. If you make the pinhole larger, the image of that point becomes a larger circle. But nearby points, who would focus on slightly different position on the camera, would produce larger circles, which will overlap in the image, and everything becomes blurry.

The impulse response tells you how big is the image of a point. Let's call the point $A=(l,0)$, with $l<0$, the center of the pinhole $O=(0,0)$ and the center of the image $B=(l',0)$. Let's call $C=(0,R)$ the point on the pinhole right above $O$. A ray of light from $A$ will reach the image only if it will pass through the pinhole at a height less then $R$. At the limit, the last ray will just barely miss the pinhole's edge. It will reach the image at some point $D=(l', R')$.

Let's call $\theta=\angle OAC=\angle BAD$. The radius of the image is $$BD=AB\tan\theta$$
You have $AB=|l|+|l'|=-l+l'$, and for small angles $\tan\theta\approx\theta$, so $$BD\approx\theta(-l+l')$$
Now triangles $AOC$ and $ABD$ are similar. Then $$\frac{BD}{OC}=\frac{AB}{AO}$$
Plugging in the values, you get $$BD=\frac{(-l+l')R}{-l}=R\left(1-\frac{l'}l\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! With reference to the diagram provided by Edward Pocella in his answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3428631/356308 , everything is clear to me now.